# Sort elements through child objects

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have an `item` object with an **1:n** relation to `categories`. 
Lets say categories is a numeric value.

I tried to sort all items as per categories with setOrderings() but it doesn't work.

```
//inside findAll() in my ItemRepository 
$query->setOrderings(array("item.categories" => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING));
```

**How can i get my query to sort all items according to their child objects `categories`?**

EDIT: Example

Item1 has categories[1,2,8], Item2 has categories[1,2,5] so the ascending sort order would be: Item2, Item1

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple categories for each item? Do you sort the items by the number of categories, or by the max category, or something else?

Comment: Yes each item has multiple categories. Each category is a number (int). I want to sort the items according to their category numbers. So for example Item1 has categories[1,2,8], Item2 has categories[1,2,5]  so the ascending sort order would be: Item2, Item1

Comment: So you sort on the max category number? You should edit your question and add these examples.

Comment: yes alright, I will add the examples to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think,

```
$query->setOrderings(array("item.categories" => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING));
```

here 'item.categories' is an array variable that's why it is not working.

So you have to create a new element (ex: item.categorie) inside item object for each item (you sort based on the max category number, the value of 'item.categorie' should be this max category number). Now 'item.categorie' will be a normal variable with value like 5 or 8 etc...

Then,

```
$query->setOrderings(array("item.categorie" => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING));
```

Will work...

Comment: it will "work" but its not what i am looking for. Adding an extra "sorting" property is not possible. I will add a sort function to my ext which parses the object-storage and creates a sorted array, which is then used to make a proper output.